# Django URL user id versus userprofile id problem

Tags: django, indexing

I have a mini comunity where each user can search and find another user's profile.
Userprofile is a class model, indexed differently compared to user model class (user id is not equal to userprofile id).

But I cannot see a user profile by typing in the URL the corresponding id. I only see the profile **of the currently logged in user**.

Why is that?
I'd also want to have in my URL the username (a primary key of the user table also) and NOT the id (a number).

The guilty part of the code is:

What can I replace that request.user with so that it will actually display the user I searched for, and not the currently logged in?

```
 def profile_view(request, id):
        u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=id)
        cv = UserProfile.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)
        blog = New.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)

 return render_to_response('profile/publicProfile.html',
        {
            'u':u,
            'cv':cv,
            'blog':blog,
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In file urls.py (of the accounts app):

```
url(r'^profile_view/(?P<id>\d+)/$',
    profile_view,
    name='profile_view'),
```

And in template:

```
  <h3>Recent Entries:</h3>

      {% load pagination_tags %}
      {% autopaginate list 10 %}
          {% paginate %}
      {% for object in list %}

          <li>{{ object.post }} <br />
            Voted: {{ vote.count }} times.<br />

            {% for reply in object.reply_set.all %}
                {{ reply.reply }} <br />
            {% endfor %}

            <a href=''> {{ object.created_by }}</a> <br />
            {{object.date}} <br />

            <a href = "/vote/save_vote/{{object.id}}/">Vote this</a>
            <a href="/replies/save_reply/{{object.id}}/">Comment</a> </li>
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Your url is `/accounts/profile_view/id` but your pattern goes `^profile_view/id`. Change it to `^accounts/profile_view/(?P<id>\d+)/$` - or is it just a typo?

Comment: hmm.. the url is under accounts app, so accounts is already added to my url. if i add it again, it will be twice in my url.it is the same thing, anyway

Comment: How does you template look like?

Comment: Add `print "id: %s\nname: %s"%(id, u.name)` after the `UserProfile.objects.get` line and see what it prints

Comment: if your problem's still there, show us what your template looks like, maybe you're using the wrong variables in it...

Comment: yes, you are right. my problem comes from the way i am collecting the data and display it in the template. i'll post the template also, right now.
I've edited my question a bit. thanks a lot!

Comment: i mean, for example in this line:   cv = UserProfile.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)
  how can i replace the request.user (wich obviously returns my currently logged in user)so that it will return the user i was searching?

Comment: the id in your url should relate to the user you want to view, so it is supposed to be cv = UserProfile.objects.filter(created_by = User.objects.get(pk=int(id))), if your user comes out of the User model, otherwise replace it by your user model... and I think UserProfile is the wrong model to get the cv probably?
In your template you can access the user's attributes eg. with {{ u.id }}, {{ u.name }} etc if youre passing the user as 'u' in your context!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
cv = UserProfile.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)
blog = New.objects.filter(created_by = request.user)
```

With

```
#u is UserProfile.objects.get(pk=id)
cv = UserProfile.objects.filter(created_by = u)
blog = New.objects.filter(created_by = u)
```